# За что конкретно отвечает shift /2

Tags: bat

> Удаления файлов по заданному расширения в каталогах и их подкаталогах. Расширение и каталог задается параметром пакетного файла. Удаленные файлы вывести.

За что конкретно отвечает shift /2 ?

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto end
pushd %1
if "%2"=="" goto end
:work
erase /s *.%2 //удаление файлов в каталоге
shift /2
if not "%2"=="" goto work
:end
popd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда **shift** сдвигает параметры командной строки. `shift /2` сдвигает параметры начиная со второго, то есть `%4 -> %3`, `%3 -> %2`, а `%0` и `%1` остаются без изменений.

Comment: ну скопировать и я могу. а зачем этот шифт в данном случае?

Comment: @ВадимМороз у вас первым параметром идёт директория, а последующие - расширение. Вот этот код и обрабатывает расширения в цикле по одному. Shift берет расширения по порядку.